# Selecting a finite field for polynomial factorization

Tags: finite-fields, factoring

This is a very specific question about factoring standard polynomials in the field of rationals. I have a module written which does the whole chain of square-free factoring to distinct-degree factoring in a finite field to Cantor–Zassenhaus factorization to Hensel lifting back to the field of rationals. It all works great but I don't have a good handle on how to select the prime field in which to do the finite factorization. Currently through empirical testing I use the next largest prime above the largest absolute value coefficient in the polynomial multiplied by $4$. My question is how to select the minimum prime finite field to maximize the chances of the CZ algorithm working while at the same keeping efficiency *relatively* high?

Comment: I am a relative ignoramus, but I thought that the point (may be just one point?) of using Hensel lifting is to get away with smaller primes. Something like what I tried to do [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1383119/11619). I may be wrong about this though. Another possibility is to look for several small primes such that the polynomial remains square-free mod $p$, and then try and CRT-combine the factorizations to produce several factorization modulo the product.

Comment: (cont'd) But it may not be clear how to best combine different moduli (for the purposes of lifting the factorization to rationals). Have you looked at [von zur Gathen & Gerhard](https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Computer-Algebra-Joachim-Gathen/dp/1107039037)? I would think they would be able to say something more useful about this. Several pitfalls in my approach to that example. For example, there it was GIVEN that a factorization of a certain type exists.

Comment: Anyway, as long as a prime $p$ is not a factor of the discriminant of a polynomial from $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, then the polynomials remains square-free when reduced modulo $p$.

Comment: Well thank you for confirming what I believed at the outset, that I could use relatively small primes. The problem is in my lifting implementation not in choosing the field then, and when I ran into a case that didn't work (always fine until the lifting) I would just raise the characteristic a little (always square free) and it worked, but now I know I need to go back and do it again from first principles.