# Irreducible factorization over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I have implemented Berlekamp-Hensel algorithm that provide to factor (into terms of irreducible polynomials) primitive and square-free polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$. At first, this algorithm obtains irreducible factorization of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (using Berlekamp algorithm) and then uses Hensel Lifting process to obtain factorization over $\mathbb{Z}$. But, now I want to extend this algorithm to factor polynomials over field $\mathbb{Q}$. I try to use following idea:

1. For any polynomial $u(x)=u_0+u_1x+u_2x^2+...+u_nx^n \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, where $u_i=\frac{a_i}{b_i}\in \mathbb{Q}$ we can define $\operatorname{LCM}(b_0,...,b_1)=M$
2. So, we can consider the polynomial $v(x)=Mu(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$
3. Then, $u(x)=\frac{v(x)}{M}=\frac{1}{M}\operatorname{content}(v(x))\operatorname{primitivepart}(v(x))$
4. And then we need to factor $\operatorname{primitivepart}(v(x))$ over $\mathbb{Z}$

Since Berlekamp-Hensel algorithm works with the primitive and square-free polynomial, we need obtain square-free polynomial. Therefore, my question is: at what step should I apply square-free factorization algorithm ? For the most initial polynomial $u(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ or for the corresponding primitive polynomial $\operatorname{primitivepart}(v(x)) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ ? And I know that there are separate square-free algorithms for the $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and for the $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. So, which one should I use ?

Comment: IIRC a standard trick to getting the square-free part of the polynomial $f(x)$ is to calculate $\gcd(f(x),f'(x)$. After all, if $p(x)^a$ divides $f(x)$, $a>1$, then $p(x)^{a-1}\mid f'(x)$. To have Euclid for calculating that gcd you need to work over a field. So I would try and do this in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ and only clear the denominators after that initial step. But, I have never implemented this, so I don't know of all possible pitfalls.

Comment: Don't you also need to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to deal with, for example the cases where the polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ but reducible modulo all primes? Or how do you deal with that?

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen . So, do you recommend applying the square-free algorithm to the original polynomial $u(x)$? That is, don't even take the $LCM $ out of the $u(x)$ polynomial ? And can we get such that after applying the square-free algorithm to the original polynomial $u(x)$, we get, for example, $u(x) = (p_1(x))^2 (p_2(x))^5$ and some of the polynomials $p_1(x)$ or $p_2(x)$ will not be square-free in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ? Or if polynomial $p_1(x)$ or $p_2(x)$  is square free in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, this means that $p_1(x)$ or $p_2(x)$ is also square-free in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ?

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen. No, I don't use the Chinese remainder theorem. This case is handled when I determine the true factors after the Hensel Lifting process.

Comment: The gcd in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ does not see constant factors at all. What do you mean "after Hensel llifting"? The Hensel lifting I'm aware runs indefinitely to higher and higher powers of $p$. You need some kind of a stopping condition.

Comment: For example, you can keep on factoring $x^4+1$ modulo powers of $p=5$, and lift $(x^2-2)(x^2+2)$ as long as you want. True, you can stop right away by observing that the constant term won't have factors iin required residue classes modulo $p$.

Comment: We can do [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1383119/11619), but there I had the important piece of side information that the degrees of the irreducible factors were known.

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen. The Hensel Lifting process continues until the coefficients of the original polynomial (and their factors) belong to the symmetric representation $\mathbb{Z}_p$. But in some cases, we can obtain the required factorization (verified by subtracting from the original polynomial) at some step of lifting.

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen. So, can you tell me. Am i right, if i think that if the polynomial $u(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ (with integer coefficients) is square-free, then this polynomial is also square-free in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ ?

Comment: @Michael not quite, for instance $4(x+1)$. You need to account for the content when you move to the integers.

Comment: @TokenToucan. Yes, so, the sequence of actions is as follows:
1. represent the original polynomial $u(x)=\frac{v(x)}{M}=\frac{1}{M}\operatorname{content}(v(x))\operatorname{primitivepart}(v(x))$ 2. 
Then apply the square-free (over $\mathbb{Q}$) algorithm for $primitivepart(v(x))$ and get $primitivepart (v(x)) = lc * factors$. 3. And after that apply the Berlekamp-Hensel algorithm for each $factor$